# PHP pagination script not work for search

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I used this code in my all pages. Everywhere this code work well. In case of my search page this code count all page by search words but when I click next(2nd or 3rd) page, its cannot display any item. That means sql query for 2nd or 3rd or any others pages not worked. No error also. Pagination page url goes well also.

My Search code:

```
if(isset($_POST['searchword'])){

$w = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['searchword']);

$q = strip_tags($w);   
$q = trim ($w);

$limit = 12; 

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM search_data WHERE MATCH(detail) AGAINST('+$q*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";

$execute = $dbh->query("$sql");
$rowcount = $execute->num_rows ;
if ($rowcount > 0 ) {
$row = $dbh->query($sql) ; 
while ($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()) {
$detail = $row['detail'];
$url = $row['url'];

echo $detail;
}
}
}

//Pagination
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM search_data WHERE MATCH(detail) AGAINST('+$q*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";  
$result = mysqli_query($dbh,$sql);  
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);  
$total_records = $row[0];  
if($total_records > 0){$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  }
$pagLink = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    if(!empty($total_pages)){for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
         $pagLink .= "<li><a href='".$thispage."?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>  </li>";  
    };  

    echo $pagLink . "</ul>"; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't include the searchword in your pagination link. How is the page2 supposed to know that you are filtering your results ?

Comment: Also, you are defining a $q variable in your f statement that you are trying to use outside of the statement. What if you don't pass in the if ? you sould define it before.